# Split large dataframes (pandas) into chunks (but after grouping)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, dask

I have a large tabular data, which needs to be merged and splitted by group. The easy method is to use pandas, but the only problem is memory.

**I have this code to merge dataframes:**

```
import pandas as pd;
from functools import reduce;

large_df = pd.read_table('large_file.csv', sep=',')
```

This, basically load the whole data in memory th

```
# Then I could group the pandas dataframe by some column value (say "block" )
df_by_block = large_df.groupby("block")

# and then write the data by blocks as
for block_id, block_val in df_by_block:
    pd.Dataframe.to_csv(df_by_block, "df_" + str(block_id), sep="\t", index=False)
```

The only problem with above code is memory allocation, which freezes my desktop. I tried to transfer this code to `dask` but `dask` doesn't have a neat `groupby` implementation.

**Note:** I could have just sorted the file, then read the data line by line and split as the "block" value changes. But, the only problem is that "large_df.txt" is created in the pipeline upstream by merging several dataframes.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

**Update: 
I tried the following approach but, it still seems to be memory heavy:**

```
# find unique values in the column of interest (which is to be "grouped by")
large_df_contig = large_df['contig']
contig_list = list(large_df_contig.unique().compute())

# groupby the dataframe 
large_df_grouped = large_df.set_index('contig')

# now, split dataframes
for items in contig_list:
    my_df = large_df_grouped.loc[items].compute().reset_index()
    pd.DataFrame.to_csv(my_df, 'dask_output/my_df_' + str(items), sep='\t', index=False)
```

Everything is fine, but the code

`my_df = large_df_grouped.loc[items].compute().reset_index()` 
seems to be pulling everything into the memory again.

Any way to improve this code??

Answer (score 2):

> but dask doesn't have a neat groupb

Actually, dask does have [`groupby` + user defined functions with OOM reshuffling](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html#).

You can use

```
large_df.groupby(something).apply(write_to_disk)
```

where `write_to_disk` is some short function writing the block to the disk. By default, dask uses disk shuffling in these cases (as opposed to network shuffling). Note that this operation might be slow, and it can still fail if the size of a single *group* exceeds your memory.

Comment: You might also try `dd.read_csv(...).set_index(...).to_csv(...)`

Comment: @MRocklin: You had provided this exact code in several other question on stacks. Everything is fine - the data is output in chunks, but sometime the data from different groups gets written in same chunks sometimes, and sometime data from same chunks will be in different file; all this depends upon the size of the `groupby`. My code is this: `large_df.set_index('contig').\
            to_csv('dask_output/my_df_by_grp-*.txt', sep='\t', index=True)`

Comment: @Ami Tavory: I had also tried the code given by you, but without success. Can you please add what goes inside `.apply(....)`.

Comment: @FYI: I just updated and wrote a fix. But, this fix still isn't very optimal.